# How to easily unshift and RGB image captured from a video recording?

Tags: image-processing

I am looking for a simple way of repairing images that do present a RGB shift distortion.

I don't know if this is important but the distortion comes from recording a video signal with a capture card.

The second image was obtained by making any sub-pixel < 128 equal 0 and those >128 to 255.

[image: original image]
[image: processed image]

Comment: I would like to know what is the reason for 'fixing' the image. I personally like the original version on the left better, I think it is much more readable. An OCR application may disagree though, and may find the right side image easier to process. Also important is if you will always be dealing with white text on a black background or if you have other types of images.

Comment: You guessed OCR is the reason and currently I'm trying only on this image but in the future I may need to apply the same for other colors and in this case unshifting could be a good idea. Still, I'm not sure if I should expect the same type of shifting on all images or it may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the blue channel is offset 1 px to the left relative to the red and green channels:

[image: blue shift]

If you correct for this and convert to grayscale with an aggressive gamma correction you will end up with something like this:

[image: corrected]

I don't think you need to worry about the correct perceptual RGB to Grayscale conversion since this source material is monochromatic. In other words, all channels can be given equal weight.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want the best image for OCR, what I recommend is that you just convert the image to black & white before doing the OCR.

The method I would use for this conversion is to first convert each RGB pixel to grayscale, using this formula:

```
P = 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B
```

Then, as a first try, make the pixel in the processed image white if P >= 128 or black otherwise.

Based on experimentation you may find that separating black and white pixels at the middle of the gray scale is not the best, so you can change it. For example, if your B&W image turns out too noisy, you may want to send less pixels to white by raising the threshold (i.e. try P>=160 instead of P>=128). Conversely, if the B&W picture lost a lot of detail you may need to lower the threshold and let more pixels go to white.

I hope this helps.